# Trying to write a function to return false if error occurs

Tags: java, processing

Trying to write a public procedure/function called F5, this should accept an array of
integers which represent a strand of DNA.

The function checks to see if there are any
errors and returns false if there are and true (OK) if not.

An error will occur if there is
a value greater than 4 or less than 0 anywhere in the array. For example the array
{0,3,2,3,1}     would return true and the array {0,2,4,4,2,1,3,5,4}
would return false.

This is in processing java btw
need help guidance and correction

code so far is incorrect:

```
public boolean F5( int numbers) 
{ 
   for( int i = 0 ; i < numbers ; i++ ) 
   {
       if(numbers[i] => 4) return false;  
   }
   return true; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

3 issues:

1) You need to pass int[] not int:

```java
public boolean F5(int[] numbers)
                     ^^
```

2) Instead of checking `i < numbers` you want to do `i < numbers.length`:

```java
for( int i = 0 ; i < numbers.length ; i++ ) {
                            ^^^^^^^
```

3) It seems you want to check if the value is "less than 0" or "more than 3":

```java
if(numbers[i] < 0 || numbers[i] > 3)return false;
```

Read as "if numbers sub i is less than 0 or numbers sub i is more than 3 then return false".

Answer (score 0):

You should change your parameter of your F5 function to int[].

```
public boolean F5(int[] numbers) {
    for (int currentNumber : numbers) {
        if (currentNumber < 0 || currentNumber >= 4) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to the function has to be an array (`int[] numbers`):

```java
public boolean F5(int[] numbers) { 

    for (int i = 0 ; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] < 0 || numbers[i] >= 4)
            return false;  
    }
    return true; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use java stream.
"allMatch" example :

```
    public static boolean F5(int[] numbers) {
        return Arrays.stream(numbers).allMatch(n -> n >= 0 && n <= 4);
    }
```

"anyMatch" example :

```
    public static boolean F5(int[] numbers) {
        return !Arrays.stream(numbers).anyMatch(n -> n < 0 || n > 4);
    }
```

Comment: For someone learning Processing and struggling with a simple "or" condition, streams may not be the best way to go about this.

Comment: I just wanted to give a different perspective. But you are right.